# Sequelize: cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am experiencing an error using Sequelize and cannot figure out what the problem is.

I am creating a new record but after the record gets created it returns the results and then catches an exception and says the value is undefined. The record gets created but returns an error. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Here is my sql table

```js
user_registration = conn.sequelize.define('user_registration',{
    idUserRegistration:{
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement:true
    },
    email:{
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    firstName:{
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    lastName:{
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    guid:{
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1
    },
    createDate:{
      type: Sequelize.DATE, defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
    }
  },{
   freezeTableName: true
 }
)
```

Here is the script for executing the statement

```html
var 
 conn = require('../../mysql/mysqlConn')
,sequelize = require('sequelize')
,mysql = require('mysql')
,userRegistration = require('../../mysql/tables').user_registration

var createAccount = function(user,callback){

    console.log('create user:',user.email)

    var results = {}

    try{

        userRegistration.create({
            email: user.email, 
            firstName: user.firstName, 
            lastName: user.lastName
        })
        .then(function(userRes){ 
            console.log('userRegistration Results:',userRes)
            results.error = false
            results.results = userRes
            callback(results)    
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log('Caught error in createRegistration!')
            console.log(err)
            results.error = true
            results.results = err
            callback(results)
        })

    }catch(e){
        console.log('EXCEPTION: error in createRegistration')
        console.log(e)
        results.error = true
        results.results = 'Error occurred creating user registration:',e
        callback(results)
    }
    
}

exports.createAccount = createAccount
```

And here is the results with error that was encountered

```html
create user: jsmith@me.com
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `user_registration` (`idUserRegistration`,`email`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`guid`,`create
Date`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'jsmith@me.com','John','Smith','a6193d70-198b-11e7-b0f0-93c15705c5db','2017-04-04 23:08:43');
userRegistration Results: Instance {
  dataValues:
   { guid: 'a6193d70-198b-11e7-b0f0-93c15705c5db',
     createDate: 2017-04-04T23:08:43.000Z,
     idUserRegistration: 10,
     email: 'jsmith@me.com',
     firstName: 'John',
     lastName: 'Smith' },
  _previousDataValues:
   { email: 'jsmith@me.com',
     firstName: 'John',
     lastName: 'Smith',
     idUserRegistration: 10,
     guid: 'a6193d70-198b-11e7-b0f0-93c15705c5db',
     createDate: 2017-04-04T23:08:43.000Z },
  _changed:
   { email: false,
     firstName: false,
     lastName: false,
     idUserRegistration: false,
     guid: false,
     createDate: false },
  '$modelOptions':
   { timestamps: false,
     instanceMethods: {},
     classMethods: {},
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: true,
     underscored: false,
     underscoredAll: false,
     paranoid: false,
     rejectOnEmpty: false,
     whereCollection: { email: 'jsmith@me.com' },
     schema: null,
     schemaDelimiter: '',
     defaultScope: {},
     scopes: [],
     hooks: {},
     indexes: [],
     name: { plural: 'user_registrations', singular: 'user_registration' },
     omitNul: false,
     sequelize:
      Sequelize {
        options: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        dialect: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        modelManager: [Object],
        connectionManager: [Object],
        importCache: {},
        test: [Object],
        queryInterface: [Object] },
     uniqueKeys: {},
     hasPrimaryKeys: true },
  '$options':
   { isNewRecord: true,
     '$schema': null,
     '$schemaDelimiter': '',
     attributes: undefined,
     include: undefined,
     raw: undefined,
     silent: undefined },
  hasPrimaryKeys: true,
  __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
  isNewRecord: false }
Caught error in createRegistration!
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I write your code in my project! but it work well, could you show your *mysqlConn*

Comment: Could you also post the code of the `callback` which is passed in? It seems that the error might be there, as the result succeeds, then errors after returning the data.

Comment: Turns out the issue was in the statement that was returning the result! I was trying to read the email the results.dataValues but I was not referencing the values correctly. Thanks everybody for helping me solve this problem!